# Do I need to manually disconnect the sender and the response function after the sender being released?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt programming, this is a simple tcp server new connection coming code,

```
void TcpServerTest::onSeverReadyRead(int clientId)
{
    qDebug() << clientId;
    qDebug() << clientSocket[clientId]->readAll();
}

void TcpServerTest::onNewConnection(/*QTcpSocket* socket*/) {
    QTcpSocket* serverRecordClient = server->nextPendingConnection();
    
    static int iClientIdGenerator = 1000;
    int iClientId = iClientIdGenerator++;
    clientSocket.insert(iClientId, serverRecordClient);
    
    connect(serverRecordClient, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [this, iClientId](){
        onSeverReadyRead(iClientId);
        });

}
```

When a new connection is coming, onNewConnection will be triggered and we bind a network data process function `onSeverReadyRead(iClientId)` with this client -- serverRecordClient.

I think when the client disconnect from the server, do I need to explicitly disconnect the binding too?

```
disconnect(serverRecordClient, &QTcpSocket::readyRead)
```

Comment: Simply delete `serverRecordClient` When you are done with this connection. That will also disconnect all signals.

Comment: serverRecordClient  is obtained from `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()`, I think QTcpServer would manage it automatically and I shouldn't directly delete it. I should just wait the network-connection disconnected, it will be released by QTcpServer.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection): "The socket is created as a child of the server, which means that it is automatically deleted when the QTcpServer object is destroyed. It is still a good idea to delete the object explicitly when you are done with it, to avoid wasting memory." If you don't, all the `QTcpSocket` instances, from all connections ever handled, will hang around in memory for as long as the server runs. It's a slow leak, essentially.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Great! Thanks! I had been worried, if I delete them, when QTcpServer auto delete them that would fails (Now I know it wouldn't).